# How to view or reset root password on google compute VM

Tags: linux, passwords, root

I have a Google VM on Linux OS. I only have console user access to a normal user

When I try to change the OS login to root using the command `"su -"`, the last password I remember is not working.

When searching how to reset the root password, the command was `"sudo password root"`, I am not able to reset the password

```
---------------------------------
 sudo passwd root
Changing password for user root.
New password:
Retype new password:
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
--------------------------------------------
```

My question, how can I reset the root password on Google Console?

Comment: If you're not allowed to do it through `sudo` (which is likely) you probably cannot do it from the shell. are you able to reboot the vm ? ifso you could boot into rescue or singleuser mode (or really just into any linux installer- or livecd) -> then you open a shell, mount your main disk (the one with /etc on it) and you can change the passwd there.

Comment: Why do you want to change the password ? You can to that directly on the google console.